# How to hash passwords in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, encryption

How I will make every password in my user table encrypted(md5()) except one particular row using a single query?

Comment: Well, MD5 isn't encryption. It's a hash function. You can't decrypt it.

Answer (score 18):

```
UPDATE table SET Password = MD5(Password)
```

I will say though that MD5 isn't a very good level of encryption and you should consider something stronger such as ENCRYPT with a custom salt.  Read about it [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/encryption-functions.html#function_md5)

EDIT:  Looks like the original question changed.  Here's the altered query to accomodate

```
UPDATE table SET Password = MD5(Password) WHERE ID!=[specified index]
```

EDIT:  Worth noting

[MD5 Encryption Hacked](http://www.gearfuse.com/md5-algorithm-hacked-by-playstation-3-cluster/)

Comment: It is fine except that it's been hacked http://www.gearfuse.com/md5-algorithm-hacked-by-playstation-3-cluster/

Comment: What if the password is encrypted with md5() with salt? How about double salting? Still hack-able?

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the OP's question, as it hashes *every* row, and the OP wants to hash every row *except one*.

Comment: Ben: the OP edited his question later to add this information.

Comment: The "hacked" link has absolutely nothing to do with password verification. I wish people would quit calling MD5 "broken" when they don't understand anything about the actual vulnerability.

Comment: MD5 in MySQL doesn't allow a salt (or double salt for that matter)

Comment: Sure it does, you just concatenate the salt string(s) onto the front/end of the password. That's what salting md5 is.

Comment: Well...that's just clever...never thought about that one.

Comment: it is 2015 now! use of MD5 should be avoided

Answer (score 7):

### Hash Functions in MySQL

There are a lot more hash functions than MD5 to use for storing passwords in you MySQL database.
You can find a list of them on [MySQL :: 11.10.2. Encryption and Compression Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/encryption-functions.html).

### Save Password (hash):

```
UPDATE users SET password = SHA('secret_password') WHERE ....;
```

### Check Password:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE name = 'username' && password = SHA('typed_password');
```

If the result is > 0, the user provided the correct password.

Answer (score 5):

When hashing passwords, do not forget to salt them, so that same passwords do not yield same hashes:

```
SET @salt := CONV(FLOOR(RAND() * 0x100000000), 10, 16)

UPDATE  passwords
SET     password = CONCAT(@salt, SHA(CONCAT(@salt, @typed_password)))

SELECT  1
FROM    passwords
WHERE   SHA(CONCAT(SUBSTRING(password, 1, 8), @typed_password)) = SUBSTRING(password, 9, 40)
```

Comment: You need to pad your salt with zeroes: LPAD(@salt, 8, '0');

Comment: select CONCAT(lpad(@salt,8,'0'), SHA(CONCAT(lpad(@salt,8,'0'), @typed_password)));

Answer (score 3):

Edited in response to edit in OP.

```
UPDATE userTable
SET password = MD5(password)
WHERE NOT (<criteria to identify row to exclude>)
```

Comment: it is 2015 now! use of MD5 should be avoided

Comment: Agreed. https://security.stackexchange.com/a/31846/29869   && https://security.stackexchange.com/a/19908/29869

Answer (score 3):

Concerning you edit: do you have an ID or username that identifies this row?

```
UPDATE mytable
SET password = MD5(password)
WHERE id <> 123
```

Comment: it is 2015 now! use of MD5 should be avoided

Answer (score 2):

I think it is a little bit more update

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'existinguser'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('newpass');
```

or

```
UPDATE user SET  password = PASSWORD('newpass');
```

Hope this help

Comment: And better yet is to combine the answer of @Quassnoi thus, usining a stored salt per password and a server wide pepper. "UPDATE user SET password = PASSWORD(CONCAT(salt, typed_password, pepper))"