# SQL query/PHP to import users from one table to another, but hashing the password?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, password-encryption

I have 2 tables - old and new.

Starting from ID 5000 until ID 10000, I need to import data from the old into the new table.

Let's just say "Name" and "Password" needs to be imported.

In the old table the users are not hashed! How can i import name and password but ensure that the imported password is hashed, ie: "$P$B....." (wordpress hash)? Can this be done via an SQL query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like below

```
INSERT INTO new_table (col1, password, ..., coln)
SELECT col1, MD5(password), ..., coln
FROM old_table
WHERE ID BETWEEN 5000 to 10000;
```

Please refer [MySQL Password Hashing](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/password-hashing.html) available.

Read more

[How to hash passwords in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704194/how-to-hash-passwords-in-mysql)

Comment: Thanks. Just realised I need to use http://www.openwall.com/phpass/ so it may be a two step process..

Comment: I'm glad that I could help you

Answer (score 0):

If you're just using something that MySQL has natively to hash with, such as md5, you can just do something like

```
INSERT INTO NewTable (ID, Name, Password)
  SELECT ID, Name, md5(Password) AS Password
  FROM OldTable
  WHERE ID BETWEEN 5000 to 10000
```

If you need to use a different hash than MD5, check MySQL's docs for what else they support. If it's something custom like you said, Word Press's hash (I have no idea what they use), you'll have to run through each one in PHP and convert them over manually.

Comment: Thanks Mark. Looks like it uses PHPass which I don't think works with mysql.. http://www.openwall.com/phpass/