# Using php functions in mysql update queries

Tags: php, mysql

```
$sql2 ="UPDATE table1,table2 SET table2.password2 = ".password_hash(."table1.password1".,PASSWORD_DEFAULT)." WHERE table1.username = table2.username";
```

I am trying to use Php functions in Mysql update queries instead of iteration, but it doesn't seem to work. Please let me know if there is anyway I can achieve this without iteration, if with Stored procedures I can, please give a small example as I have never made a stored procedure before, thanks in advance

Comment: Please define “it doesn’t seem to work.” Errors? Wrong behavior?

Comment: @Sami Kuhmonen , the code works but it does hash the entire column instead considers it as a value and not a column

Comment: Are you trying to use a php function where a mysql function should be?  Your built query string will be built in php-land and then shipped away to database-land as a static string.  If the intended bulk hashing is even possible via mysql, I am confident that this is not the way.  I don't know all of the mysql tricks, but you may need to perform iterated updates.

Comment: Perhaps this ancient page will lead you in the right direction to research: https://stackoverflow.com/q/704194/2943403

Answer (score -2):

The below code is working good for you :) .

```
$sql2 ="UPDATE table1,table2 SET table2.password2 = '".password_hash("table1.password1",PASSWORD_DEFAULT) ."' WHERE table1.username = table2.username";
```

Answer (score -2):

Try With This Below Query:

```
"UPDATE table2 SET table2.password2 = (SELECT '".password_hash("table1.password1",PASSWORD_DEFAULT) ."'from table1 WHERE  table1.username = table2.username)"
```

Answer (score -2):

You are missing single quote, You can try like this

```
$pass = password_hash("table1.password1",PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$sql2 ="UPDATE table1,table2 SET table2.password2 = '$pass' WHERE table1.username = table2.username";
```